# Converting 2015-12-04 17:02:10 +00:00 time to microseconds

Tags: php, time

I have a time string in `2015-12-04 17:02:10 +00:00` format.

I want to convert this string in `mircoseconds decimal(16,4)` like `1449825379.3464`

How can I convert this in PHP? I tried it by using:

```
echo strtotime("2015-12-04 17:02:10 +00:00");
```

But it just returns `1449248530` without the microseconds.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: **[NOTE : Stack Overflow Is Not A Coaching Centre.]**

Comment: i tried  echo strtotime("2015-12-04 17:02:10 +00:00"); and it returns 1449248530

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it but you should provide milliseconds in your date string.

```
<?php
$date = new DateTime('2015-12-04 17:02:10.4418 +00:00');
$microseconds = (float) $date->format('U.u');
echo $microseconds; //prints 1449248530.4418
```